# How do I uniquely identify tables that I have inserted?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I need to insert some tables into a Google Docs via a script and then periodically update only the tables I've inserted via the script. I don't want to modify other tables that were inserted without the script...just change those inserted by the script. However, I don't see a way to place an attribute or unique name to each table. Is there a way to do that?

`var table = body.insertTable(insertPoint, [[row.join("")]]);`

Comment: In your script, can you use `insertPoint` for retrieving the table you need?

Comment: That's a good suggestion but I am not able to save insertPoint anywhere so I can reference it later when I need to use it. Also, the document will most likely change and insertPoint isn't dependable.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. Unfortunately, in the current stage, the table in Google Document has not unique ID. By this, the specific table cannot be directly retrieved. In your case, how about these 2 workarounds? 1. from the order of tables, the specific table is retrieved using the array of `getTables()`. 2. If the specific text in the table, the specific table is retrieved using `findText()`. If those were not the direction you want, I apologize again.

Comment: Please don't apologize! I appreciate your help! Is there a way to hide text? Perhaps I can hide the text so the user doesn't see it then I can use findText()

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, for example, how about putting a table after a text which has the same color with the background color? By this, I think that the text can be used as the hidden unique ID for the table.

Comment: I proposed a workaround for achieving your issue as an answer. Could you please confirm it? That is one of several possible workarounds. If that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the specific table using Google Apps Script.
- You want to put the table using `var table = body.insertTable(insertPoint, [[row.join("")]]);`.
- The place and order of tables are changed.

For this, how about this answer?

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, the table in Google Document cannot have the unique ID. By this, the specific table cannot be directly retrieved. In your case, in order to achieve above goal, in this answer, I would like propose the following workaround.

- When the table is inserted, a text is added to the upper side of table as the unique ID. The unique ID is apparently hidden by modifying the font color to the same with the background color and modifying the font size to 1.
- When the table is retrieved, the specific table is retrieved using the unique ID.

### Sample script:

#### For inserting a table:

```
function putTable() {
  const documentId = "###";  // Please set Document ID.
  const uniqueIdOfTable = "tableId1";  // Please set the unique table ID. In this sample, "tableId1" is used.
  const insertPoint = 1;  // In this sample, "1" is the minumum size.
  const row = ["a1", "b1", "c1"];

  const body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
  const table = body.insertTable(insertPoint, [[row.join("")]]);
  const text = table.getPreviousSibling().asParagraph().appendText("\n" + uniqueIdOfTable);
  text.setFontSize(1).setForegroundColor(text.getBackgroundColor() || "#ffffff");
}
```

- When you run this script, a table is inserted and the unique ID of `tableId1` is added. And the unique ID is hidden by the font size and font color.

#### For retrieving the specific table using the unique ID:

```
function getTable(documentId, uniqueIdOfTable) {
  const body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
  const index = body.getChildIndex(body.findText(uniqueIdOfTable).getElement().getParent());
  const element = body.getChild(index + 1);
  return element.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE ? element.asTable() : null;
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  const documentId = "###";  // Please set Document ID.
  const uniqueIdOfTable = "tableId1";  // Please set the unique table ID. In this sample, "tableId1" is used.
  const table = getTable(documentId, uniqueIdOfTable);

  console.log(table.editAsText().getText())
}
```

- When you run `main()`, the table is retrieved using the unique ID of `tableId1`. In this case, `getTable()` returns the table object.

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script for explaining the workaround. So please modify this for your actual situation.